# Collect Values + Model Builder ArcGIS 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder

I have a question relating to the use of Collect Values in Model Builder.

I've just come across this post ([Piping output of Iterate Raster tool into Raster Calculator tool using ModelBuilder?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54937/modelbuilder-how2-pipe-output-of-iterate-raster-tool-into-raster-calculator-too/134557#134557)) and it's pretty much the same as what I want to do. I'm also adding in a user defined weighting to the iteration and then attempting to collect the values before running the cell statistics. The problem is that I'm not getting a set of unique outputs at the Output Values stage and it only return results for the last original rasters.

Any idea where I'm going wrong with this?

[image]

Comment: Can you show us whats going on in the Raster Calculator?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Just to clarify what I'm trying to do....I want to let the user select a number of raster layers to go into a sensitivity analysis (this analysis be run using cell stats at the end of the model - using values stored in output values). Prior to this the user can also add their own weights (1-3) to each selected raster (see Weights1). The raster calc then runs this initial processing and I'm trying to pass the results to Output Values.

Comment: In addition to this I'm trying to find a way of limiting the number of raster layers that go into the iteration. At the moment everything in the .gdb goes it but ideally a checkbox in the GUI is what I am looking for. Thanks again Hornbydd

Comment: The way to filter using an Iterator is to use the wildcard parameter, for example "qw*" will only pick up rasters that start with "qw".

Comment: Just looking at this model as-is, it seems to be OK but we need to see whats going on in the raster calculator as that is white indicating either invalid parameters or an incomplete tool...

Comment: This is the expression in the raster calc: "%c_dembuf65%" * float(%Weights1%). The resulting raster is then RC_Results and is the input value for Collect Values

Comment: What is the output raster name in your raster calculator?

Comment: Hi, the output is RC_Results

Comment: Ok thats your problem. You need to give each raster a unique name, otherwise you are overwriting it. Replace the output name with %Name% which is the variable generated by the Iterator.

Comment: OK - like such C:\Projects\Test\Test.gdb\%Name% Appreciate the help

Comment: where are the Output Values going? I'm trying to use this tool to tabulate the number of points captured by the intersection of a points FC with a number of polygon FCs.